# Storing large jsons on blob field on a oracle database

Tags: java, json, oracle

As the title says, I need to store some big json files on a "blob" field on a oracle database. We've been using the "[utl_raw.cast_to_raw](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71383)" function, which seems to be the suggested way to do it, but we quickly hit the 2000 byte size cap.

I've been looking around for a solution, and the only one I've found points towards [converting the Json to a byte array through a webservice](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1197481/Storing-JSON-Objects-in-BLOBS-in-Oracle) (We are using Java instead of C#, but it shouldn't be an issue).

There's something else we can do to get our big jsons on the database without having to relay on a new development?

Comment: As BLOB can be any binary stuff, the solution is quite independend on what you store in a BLOB. Just look around for Oracle and BLOB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CLOB type column, it can store GB of text. It´s not as easy to do CRUD operations with it, but nothing you can´t handle

Comment: Great, somehow the question is getting downvoted but that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!